# FFmpeg – Concatenating multiple MP4 files

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I am using an external script (http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#extscript) to concatenate multiple MP4 files. This script lets you do a command like this:

```
./mmcat input1 input2 input3 ... output
```

to concatenate multiple files.

I am using this command right now:

```
./mmcat.sh video1.mp4 video2.mp4 video3.mp4 "output.mp4"
```

After getting an "Operation not permitted" error, I logged the results, which are listed below:

**In log.v.3 and log.v.2:**

[yuv4mpegpipe @ 00000190aa080a20] ERROR: Codec not supported.

Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input

**In log.a.2:**
Temp/mcs_a2.lnk: Permission denied

**In log.a.3:**
...AppData/Local/Temp/mcs_a3.lnk':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream

I would appreciate any help, as I'm very new to using ffmpeg and just a beginner at video encoding etc., in general.

Comment: I've never tried that script, but you may be able to just use the concat demuxer instead as shown in that same link.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, then found [this post](http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2015-December/185681.html) in its mailing list after weeks of debugging.

Worked for me after removing every occurrence of `-vcodec $PARAM` [1] in `mmcat` script.

[1]: `$PARAM` is not literal, it's whatever value used for `ffmpeg`'s `-vcodec` option in the script.